# Moving laravel 5.4 from localhost to server issue: uses localhost paths

Tags: php, localhost, live, laravel-5.4

I moved files and folders frm public directory to the root of my laravel project, uploaded to a sub directory on my hosting so it looks like this www.example.com/social. In .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_URL=http://www.example.com/social/
```

In index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

When I try th view the project I get this error

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [welcome] not found.
in FileViewFinder.php line 137
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\social\\resources\\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
```

So hot to fix this issue to make it work as it should? It's first time Moving a laravel project to the server so no experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this commands on the server laravel directory:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: if you have ssh acces its fine

Comment: The problem is with connecting to the server always have to whitelist my IP and get access denied a lot even if whitelisted. Any other way to run these commands?

Comment: stop the local server, run the command locally, delete the laravel directory on the server and reupload